# How do you stop source from abbreviating function names?

Tags: r, function, abbreviation

I am trying to source multiple functions, that differ by a number in the name.

For example: func1, func2.

I tried using "func_1", and "func_2", as well as putting the number first, "1func" and "2func". No matter how I index the function names, the source function just reads in one function that it calls `"func"` - which is not what I want.

I have tried using for-loops and sapply:

**for-loop:**

```
func.list <- list.files(path="/some_path",pattern="some pattern",full.names=TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(func.list)){
source(func.list[i])
}
```

**sapply:**

```
sapply(func.list,FUN=source)
```

I am going to be writing multiple versions of a data correction function, and would really like to be able to index them - because giving a concise, but specific, name would be difficult, and not allow me to selectively source just the function files from their directory.

In my code, func.list gives the output (I have replaced the actual directory because of privacy/contractual issues):

```
[1] "mypath/1resp.correction.R" 
[2] "mypath/2resp.correction.R"
```

Then when I source func.list with either the for-loop or sapply code (listed above), R only loads one function named resp.correction, with the code body from "2resp.correction.R".

Comment: This does not sound like standard source behavior, please make your example.reproducible.

Comment: You certainly *can't* put the number first, like `1func`- that's not a legal identifier in R (or most languages).

Comment: @David Robinson: Thanks for your input. Just for further clarification I have tried (with no success) using the following formats: "func1", "func_1", and "1func".

Comment: @Paul Hiermstra I did my best to edit the code, to make the example reproducible. I am not sure what else I could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `source` is a file name, not a function name. So you cannot be fancy here: you need to provide the exact filenames.

It sounds like your two files contain the definitions of a function with the same name (`resp.correction`) in both files, so yes, as you source one file after the other, the function is overwritten in your global environment.

You could, inside your loop, reassign the function to a different name:

```
func.list <- list.files(path="/some_path",pattern="some pattern",full.names=TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(func.list)) {
   source(func.list[i], local = TRUE)
   assign(paste0("resp.correction", i), resp.correction, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realize now that I did not change the function name in the files. I feel like a huge moron, but thank you again.